# Python Boto3 - print ec2 instance with specific tag Key

Tags: python, boto3

I have 350 ec2 instances that I need to get some information from I am using the code

```
#Instance id,Instance type,Instance State,Instance Name
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
Myec2=client.describe_instances()
for pythonins in Myec2['Reservations']:
 for printout in pythonins['Instances']:
  for printname in printout['Tags']:
   print(printout['InstanceId'], printout['InstanceType'], printname['Value'])
```

The problem is the instances are tagged with 3 key value pairs and the code is repeating for and printing output 3x for each instances using the different tags.

I only want to print out result for instance with tag Key = Name.

the output right now is

```
i-0e8d25ed03569252a t3a.medium DB002-old
i-0e8d25ed03569252a t3a.medium NW02
i-0e8d25ed03569252a t3a.medium daily

i-0738894210d94f6d0 t3a.2xlarge DB110-new
i-0738894210d94f6d0 t3a.2xlarge daily
i-0738894210d94f6d0 t3a.2xlarge NW02
```

desired output

```
i-0e8d25ed03569252a t3a.medium DB002-old
i-0738894210d94f6d0 t3a.2xlarge DB110-new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used 'resource' instead of 'client'. Maybe this code will suit your needs:

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance_iterator = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['Name']}])
for instance in instance_iterator:
    for tag in instance.tags:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
            print(instance.id, instance.instance_type, 'Name :', tag['Value'] )
```

And also because you have more than 100 instances it would be better to use resource instead of client

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by adding

```
for printname in printout['Tags']:
   if printname['Key'] == 'Name':
```